# Prove that if $A$ is positive, then $\exists\;\alpha>0$ such that $\langle Ax, x \rangle\geq \alpha|x|^2$ for $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R}).$ We say that $A$ is positive if $\langle Ax, x \rangle>0$ for $x\neq 0.$

I want to prove that if $A$ is positive, then $\exists\;\alpha>0$ such that

$\langle Ax, x \rangle\geq \alpha|x|^2$ for $x\in\Bbb{R}^n.$

Please, I need help for this! Proofs and references will be highly regarded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is positive implies that $\langle A(x),x\rangle=f(x)>0$. The restriction of $f$ on $S^{n-1}$ has a minimum $\alpha>0$. For every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n, f({x\over{\|x\|}})\geq\alpha$ implies that $\langle A({x\over{\|x\|}},{x\over{\|x\|}})\geq \alpha$ and $\langle A(x),x\rangle \geq \alpha\|x\|^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\alpha=\min_{|x|=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle$. Why does the minimum attained?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda>0$ be an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$  (recall that positive $A$ implies,  there exists a $\lambda>0$ . Then $A x =\lambda x$

\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{T} A x &=& \lambda  x^{T} x 
&=& \lambda \left \lVert x \right\rVert^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^{T} A x } {\left \lVert x \right\rVert^{2}} &=& \lambda  >0
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be positive, then $$\langle Ax, x \rangle>0$$
We can easily find $\alpha$ such that 
$$\langle (A - \alpha I) x, x \rangle>0$$
Let $\alpha = \lambda_{min}(A) - \epsilon$ for $0 < \epsilon < \lambda_{min}(A)$. For that choice, you can get from the equation
$$\langle A x, x \rangle -  \alpha \langle x, x \rangle>0$$
or
$$\langle A x, x \rangle > \alpha \langle x, x \rangle$$